# How to deal with sequential calling event handlers?

Tags: c#, events

*Before I reinvent the wheel...*

This is just an **EXAMPLE** for describing the problem -- let's say you have a backend with collection of some data, and frontend which displays one item of the collection.

At the backend I have ItemIndex -- whenever it changes, it fires up OnScroll event.

I also have AddNewItem method, it adds new item at the end of the collection. The end of the method is calling OnNewItem event handler.

And here is the catch -- in AddNewItem I have to change ItemIndex, which fires OnScroll. One of the receivers of both (!) OnScroll and OnNewItem if frontend which displays selected item.

In such case it is called twice (not good). One solution would be altering item_index instead of ItemIndex, and this way preventing OnScroll, but I don't like it because ItemIndex does not act as black box anymore.

Is there any established pattern for sequential firing events, and sending only "important" ones (here: OnNewItem overrides OnScroll)? My idea would be to define an event scope, then instead of sending events directly, just register them for sending, and at the close of scope sort them and send the required ones.

In general -- **question** -- how should I deal with potential sequential event triggering. Use internals to avoid sending redundant events? Ignore the overhead? ...?

Comment: Like that question. Wonder about this myself. My solution always was setting the field directly, or have some ItemIndexInternal that wouldn't fire the event.

Comment: Mine too, but if my program gets bigger this approach will become problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems obvious to me athough I could have easily missed something:

```
private bool IsAdding { get; set; }
private int item_index;
private IList m_collection;

public void AddNewItem(object item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Cannot add null item."); // little bit of contracting never hurts
    }

    m_collection.Add(item);
    IsAdding = true;
    ItemIndex = collection.Count - 1; //I'm just making assumptions about this piece but it is not important how you decide what your index is to answer the question

    if (OnNewItem != null)
    {
       OnNewItem(this, EventArgs.Empty); 
    }
}

public int ItemIndex
{
   get { return item_index =; }
   set
   {
       item_index = value;
       if (!IsAdding && OnScroll != null) //won't double fire event thanks to IsAdding
       {
           OnScroll(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       }
       IsAdding = false; //need to reset it
   }
}
```

One thing I would note is that you made mention of just simply altering item_index directly but that wouldn't have a blackbox behavior. Well black box is all well and good ... but that term only applies to objects interacting with this class we have been discussing.

You should feel empowered to use the internals of your class within itself. It is not good OOP to blackbox items within itself. If you are doing that then your class probably has design issues where it should be split into multiple classes.

Comment: Good points about the design, however I nevertheless prefer blackboxing -- with loading, saving, adding, deleting, and so on, it is easy to miss something. It is better to spend time on more solid design, than searching for bugs because each method assumes something about other methods. I will use your idea with IsAdding, but rather change it to EventPending and checking if current one has bigger or smaller priority.

Comment: @macias to each his own =P Your naming convention probably will make more sense. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a 'latch' of some form.  When updating, you perform your UI actions via a helper which sets a flag saying 'hey, I'm in a special state!'.  Then, when raising events, you check to see if the latch is set -- if it is, you skip raising those events.

It's basically a very simple, generalised version of what Matthew posted.  Depending on the situation, setting a flag may be more than adequate.

[Jeremy Miller's explanation is worth reading](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/02/build-your-own-cab-12-rein-in-runaway-events-with-the-quot-latch-quot/)

Answer (score 0):

You could point both events at a single function.  The function can determine the sender and perform the appropriate action(s).

Comment: Just assign a function to the delegate like you normally do.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. My code is ItemIndex = Items.Count-1; if (OnNewItem!=null) OnNewItem(); Where do you see a place of another delegate?

Comment: I'm suggesting to bind the IndexChanged (or whatever the event is called) and the AddNewItem event to the same function.  Then you can look at the sender and determine what actions to perform.

Comment: @Jordan, I don't see how it would be possible. What if I would like to change just Index (because I just moved to another item, without adding anything)?

Comment: You should know which event was the trigger.  That way you know when you're supposed to AddNewItem vs other tasks.